# Woocommerce custom tax function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tax

I am looking to add a very specific tax calculation to the cart and "invoice plugin" as well. Flat -+ percentage doesn't work since this is a very specific case. I just have no idea how to go about it and all the resources online seem to be about woocommerce inbuilt tax classes, which are flat rates.

---

Lets define the variables:

*Final price* = X (in this case it is 100$)

*Final price is always known, since its added while creating the product in woocommerce*

*Subtotal Tax* = Y (it's 25% of X)

*Subtotal Tax - Actual Tax* = Z (it's 21% tax calculation of Y)

*Actual Tax amount* = M (y-z)

So if final price is X = **100.00**

Y = 0.25 * 100 = **25.00**

Z = 25/1.21 = **20.66**

M = 25.00 - 20.66 = **4.34** *(rounded up to 2 decimal places)*

In the cart i need to output this:

- Subtotal: (X)
- Price without tax: (X - Y)
- Price applicable with special tax: (Z)
- Special tax amount: (M)
- Total Sum: (X)

---

I found this code to add extra fees (taxes) to the cart, but nothing that would help me achieve desired result.

```
// Add CUSTOM TAX
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','custom_tax_surcharge_for_swiss', 10, 1 );
function custom_tax_surcharge_for_swiss( $cart ) {

    $percent = 25;

    // Calculation
    $surcharge = ( $cart->cart_contents_total + $cart->shipping_total ) * $percent / 100;

    // Add the fee (tax third argument disabled: false)
    $cart->add_fee( __( 'Custom Tax', 'woocommerce')." ($percent%)", $surcharge, false );

}
```

I can do the calculation myself, i just need to know how to add multiple new lines to the output so its displayed in the cart totals and later in the invoice plugin.

Comment: _"multiple new lines to the output so its displayed in the cart totals"_ - 
Adding is not a problem in itself, whether these will also be displayed in the invoice plugin completely depends on that specific plugin, and whether it is equipped for this. Since you didn't mention which specific plugin (because there are dozens of them) 
ensures that your question can only be partially answered. Mentioning the plugin wouldn't make much of a difference anyway, given questions about 3rd party plugins should be asked directly to the plugin support.

Comment: In short, focus your question on customizing WooCommerce. Mention which lines are already present on the cart page and which you want to add (between or behind existing lines)